# jsonschema: Abstract Data Type and correct error message

Tags: python, jsonschema

I'm using the `jsonschema` Python library like this:

```py
import jsonschema

schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": False,
            "required": ["key"],
            "properties": {"key": {"enum": ["foo"], "type": "string"}},
        },
        {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": False,
            "required": ["key", "baritem"],
            "properties": {
                "key": {"enum": ["bar"], "type": "string"},
                "baritem": {"type": "string"},
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

I can validate correct data:

```py
jsonschema.validate({"key": "bar", "baritem": "ok"}, schema)
```

But if a property is missing, if fails (as expected), but with a strange error message:

```py
jsonschema.validate({"key": "bar"}, schema)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "valid.py", line 29, in <module>
    jsonschema.validate({"key": "bar"}, schema)
  File "/home/david/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 934, in validate
    raise error
jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: 'bar' is not one of ['foo']

Failed validating 'enum' in schema[0]['properties']['key']:
    {'enum': ['foo'], 'type': 'string'}

On instance['key']:
    'bar'
```

My first question is: Is it the right way to defined the `JSON` schema, especially the part defined the `key` with an `enum`?

My second question is: Is there a way to define properly Abstract Data Type like this with `jsonschema`, ie to tell `jsonschema` to choose the `object` listed in `oneOf` based on the `key` property, and to validate the rest of the properties based on this object?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose which subschema to apply based on the values of other properties with `if`/`then`/`else`, as well as `dependentSchemas`: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html

Comment: Looks great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For now, my solution will be to choose the specific schema to use by myself:

```py
import jsonschema
from jsonschema.exceptions import ValidationError

schema_foo = {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": False,
    "required": ["key"],
    "properties": {"key": {"enum": ["foo"], "type": "string"}},
}

schema_bar = {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": False,
    "required": ["key", "baritem"],
    "properties": {
        "key": {"enum": ["bar"], "type": "string"},
        "baritem": {"type": "string"},
    },
}

schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "oneOf": [
        schema_foo,
        schema_bar,
    ],
}

schema_by_key = {"foo": schema_foo, "bar": schema_bar}

data = {"key": "bar"}

try:
    key = data["key"]
except KeyError:
    raise ValidationError("key is missing")

try:
    specific_schema = schema_by_key[key]
except KeyError:
    raise ValidationError("key is invalid")

jsonschema.validate(data, specific_schema)
```

So error is correctly reported:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "valid.py", line 43, in <module>
    jsonschema.validate(data, specific_schema)
  File "/home/david/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 934, in validate
    raise error
jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: 'baritem' is a required property

Failed validating 'required' in schema:
    {'additionalProperties': False,
     'properties': {'baritem': {'type': 'string'},
                    'key': {'enum': ['bar'], 'type': 'string'}},
     'required': ['key', 'baritem'],
     'type': 'object'}

On instance:
    {'key': 'bar'}
```